# How to get current and local time with Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, timer, zend-date

In my App i have to get my local time ,I used this code :

```
    $date = new Zend_Date();
$time = $date->get(Zend_Date::TIME_LONG);
```

But it gives me 7:51:00 AM UTC ,UTC time .
Can someone help me to get my local time.
Thanks.

Comment: try using `$time = $date->now()->toString('HH:mm:ss a')`

Comment: Also check which timezone is set in the php with `$dateObj->getTimezone();`

Answer (score 1):

Try This, and please refer document it is given in length in that..

```
$date->setTimezone($user->timezone);

echo $date->get(Zend_Date::TIME_SHORT);
```